# jax-rs method parameters as CDI beans

Tags: json, jax-rs, java-ee-6, cdi, bean-validation

I have simple JAX-RS bean like below:

```
@Path('/client')
class ClientResource {

    @POST
    public Response post(Client client) {
        ...
    }

}
```

`Client` is being created from json response body.
Is it possible to have `Client` class to be CDI aware bean? I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
class Client {

    @Inject
    private Validator validator;

    public String clientName;    

    public validate() {
       // use validator here
    }
}
```

By default I'm getting `validator` null, so it seems Client is not being managed.

I'm using JBoss with RESTEasy as Jax-RS implementation.

**EDIT**

I think I could provide custom mapper from JSON, but it seems to be lots of boilerplate code then.

Answer (score 0):

That should work just fine. It's possible that bean val isn't available. Try creating a producer or injecting something else.

Comment: Unfortunately whatever I inject, evaluates to `null`. I suspect that this `Client` instance is created by new bypassing CDI lifecycle and I don't know how to avoid that.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. This may be fixed in Java EE 7, but I'm not sure. And of course that doesn't help you now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JAXB for unmarshalling? I'm not familiar with RESTEasy, and although i see it can use JAXB, i don't know if that's the only option.

If you are using JAXB, then its [`Unmarshaller`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html) supports [Unmarshal Event Callbacks](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback). It can call methods on the object being unmarshalled, or, even better, a separate [event listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.Listener.html). You can register a listener which has a reference to the CDI [`BeanManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html) (obtained with a simple `@Inject`, or via JNDI at `java:comp/BeanManager`), and which uses that to inject the newly-unmarshalled object.

I am by no means a CDI expert, but an experiment indicates that this seems to inject an already-created object:

```
public class Injector<T> {

    private final BeanManager beanManager;
    private final InjectionTarget<T> injectionTarget;
    private final Bean<T> bean;

    public Injector(BeanManager beanManager, Class<T> cl) {
        this.beanManager = beanManager;
        injectionTarget = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(beanManager.createAnnotatedType(cl));
        bean = resolve(beanManager.getBeans(cl));
    }

    private Bean<T> resolve(Set<Bean<?>> beans) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) beanManager.resolve(beans);
        return bean;
    }

    public CreationalContext<T> inject(T obj) {
        CreationalContext<T> creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
        injectionTarget.inject(obj, creationalContext);
        return creationalContext;
    }

}
```

That code takes an existing instance of some class and injects dependencies into it. This is a somewhat irregular use of CDI, but it seems to work (moreover, i believe it is completely valid and supported).

Note that the calling code needs to hold on to the returned `CreationalContext`, and call its [`release`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/spi/CreationalContext.html#release%28%29) method after the object is finished with.